# Can I create a pointer in my header file, pointing to a function in another cpp file?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I have a func in my abc.cpp file

```
namespace myNamespace{

void Gif::myfunc(){
//code
}

}
```

In anotherHeader.h file:

```
void createPointer(){

void(*funcPtr)()=&Gif::myfunc;

}
```

can I do this, or anything similar?

Note: This is not abc.h, it is another header file which does not have myfunc() declaration.
Gif is a class.
I cannot use the relevant header file, since I'll be creating this anotherHeader.h using a perl script during build time.

I'm new to C++, hence it is difficult to understand the scope of namespaces/classes/pointers.

I just need to know if I can access the functions defined in another source file, in a header file and save their pointer. I will be using this set pointer again in abc.cpp file. I know the best way is to define the function pointer in abc.cpp itself, but I cannot do that, due to my project needs.

what exactly am I trying to do:
There are multiple set functions(100+) present one class, I am creating a header file dynamically which will create a map, with keys as func names and store the function pointers present in abc.cpp. I will use this map to call these functions in my abc.cpp fil using the keys.

Comment: Is `Gif` a class or is it a namespace?

Comment: Seem like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) 1. Why do you need a pointer instead of a free function? 2. Why do you need a pointer inside other source file instead of holding it in the relevant header file(Eg: `Gif.h`)?

Comment: @LouisGo I need this structure only, I cannot define the pointer in Gif.h

Comment: @JanSchultke Gif is a class

Comment: *"which does not have myfunc() declaration"* -- if `myfunc()` has not been declared, then it might as well not exist. Basic C++ syntax -- you cannot use an identifier without knowing that it is an identifier.

Comment: myfunc() is not defined/declared in anotherHeader.h, it is declared in abc.h and defined in abc.cpp

Comment: We can access a function in one source file and class, from another cpp file, I just want to know if I can do that in header file, that is, save the function pointer in a variable in header file, and use that variable in cpp file.

Comment: Ask chatgpt, less stress

Comment: If they are member functions then you will need a member function pointer and an instance of the class to call them. Can you do it in a header? Probably. Should you? If that header is included in more than one place you'll have multiple definition errors. There are potentially ways around that, but if you plan to use it in a cpp file why not declare it there and avoid the hassle?

Comment: Agree with @RetiredNinja. If only `abc.cpp` use it, then just define it in `abc.cpp`. Also it seems you're trying to achieve certain kind of reflection, you may also try to lookup some C++ reflection library if needed.

Comment: Can't the perl script that generates `anotherHeader.h` file add the line `#include "abc.h"` near the top of it? Distantly related: be aware that `void(*funcPtr)()=&Gif::myfunc;` would only compile if `myfunc` is a static member function.

Comment: Alternatively: if you can guarantee that `anotherHeader.h` would only ever be included by `abc.cpp`, and moreover included after `abc.h`, then you don't strictly need `#include "abc.h"` in `anotherHeader.h` (though it wouldn't hurt either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anotherHeader.h should have the declaration of this function.

For example, in abc.h

```
#pragma once
class Gif
{
public:
    static void myfunc();
};
```

Then in your anotherHeader.h file, just include abc.h.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, but not in the *exact* way. Instead of `void(*funcPtr)()=&Gif::myfunc`, you would do `void(Gif:: * funcPtr)()=&Gif::myfunc`. However, I believe the Gif class is in the namespace, in which case it would be `void(myNamespace::Gif:: * funcPtr)()=&Gif::myfunc`. This is because a value of type `void (myNamespace::Gif::*)()` cannot be used to initialize an entity of type `void (*)()` <- the variable.

**Edit:**  For your code work, you would have needed to include the .cpp file in the header file. That is not the ideal strategy based off guidelines in C++, as the roles are technically switched by doing so. **HOWEVER:** instead of this, a more ideal way of doing this would do be to include `createPointer` in the namespace like this, if possible:

```
// anotherHeader.h
namespace myNamespace
{
    void createPointer()
    {
        // ... your code
    }
}
```

Then, you include the header file in the cpp: `#include "anotherHeader.h"`